# Soft question: How to learn Newtonian mechanics in the best way?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I have just started a course in *statics and dynamics*. I find the course book we have lacking much more than I had anticipated with respect to rigour and giving mathematical arguments when making statements. I have decided to try to work with the book *An introduction to mechanics* (Kleppner, Kolenkow) on my own "on the side", but I am not sure if I should do it right now parallel to my course in *statics and dynamics* in order to get the most of that course or wait for the summer holidays when I have no courses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your course in statics and dynamics an engineering course that uses an engineering text? If so I understand your issue since in my opinion engineering textbooks are great for applications but do not provide the rigor in developing the basic principles that are provided in physics mechanics textbooks.  For example, engineering texts uses vectors but sometimes do not clarify that we use free vectors as discussed in physics texts.  Another example, some engineering texts do not develop the physics of non-inertial rotating coordinate systems nearly as well as physics texts do. I suggest studying the physics mechanics textbook to the extent you can with the time available along with the engineering course to better understand the basic principles, using a physics book that is not too advanced.  I am unfamiliar with the Kleppner/Kolenkow text, but maybe others can comment on it.